# How many times a shared library is loaded into memory

Tags: shared-libraries

does any one have an idea how many times a shared library is loaded into memory ? 
For example if I execute `ProgramA` and  `ProgramB` that both use `libmyLib.so`, I agree that there is only one copy on disk, but what about memory ?

PS : what about windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just one instance of shared library is shared among Program `A` & `B`

Check the [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-shlibs/index.html) which says,

```
Shared libraries can save memory, not just disk space. The kernel can keep a 
single copy of a shared library in memory, sharing it among multiple applications.
So, not only do we only have one copy of printf() on the disk, we only have one 
in memory. That has a pretty noticeable effect on performance.
```

Comment: thank you :), I guess it's the same thing for windows ?

Comment: Most probably for Windows too. Usually shared library code is not present in the program executable, which means it doesn't load every time.